# How do I sort a Dictionary<K, Dictionary<K,V>> using LINQ operations?

Tags: .net, linq, sorting, dictionary

I think this can be done in a single LINQ but cannot figure it out.  The performance of the following is OK (2 seconds on big List).  Mainly I want to get away from the memory hit of creating a List just to sort.  Need to return  dlWord21 sorted by the second int and then the first int.

```
List<DocFTSinX> docFTSinXs = new List<DocFTSinX>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<int, byte>> kvpm in dlWord21)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, byte> kvps in kvpm.Value)
    {
        docFTSinXs.Add(new DocFTSinX(kvps.Key, kvpm.Key, kvps.Value));
        //                           Word1     Word2
    }
}
dlWord21.Clear();
return docFTSinXs.OrderBy(x => x.Word1).ThenBy(x => x.Word2);
```

Comment: The problem is you will have to create a list at some point because you are clearing your source collection and so the enumerable wont work

Comment: @BobVale the above is working code.  docFTSinXs is newed and it get new values.  Hence my memory concern.

Comment: My point was if you avoid creating a list then you cannot call `dlWord21.Clear()` as the enumeration would be delayed at could possibly occur after the clear().  Hence the requirement to create a list.

Comment: @BobVale Come on, you really think I am going to prepend the excellent answer from Nick with dlWord21.Clear()? The questions was "done in a single LINQ". I put the dlWord21.Clear(); in my question to highlight the memory management concern and that I was returning a new object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631):

```
return dlWord21.SelectMany(o => o.Value, (x, y) => new DocFTSinX(y.Key, x.Key, y.Value))
               .OrderBy(x => x.Word1)
               .ThenBy(x => x.Word2);
```

Comment: only issue might be the `dlWord21.Clear()` in the source code.